# Continuous X-Ray spectrum, higher keV lower intensity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, x-rays

[image]

Why does the intensity fall with increasing x-ray energy?

Comment: Does it? The figure shows 100 kV above 60 kV.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking why the higher x-ray **energy** has lower intensity? Note that keV is a unit of energy not a unit of voltage.

Comment: Apologies, I am asking about why the higher x-ray energy has lower intensity?

Answer (score 1):

The [Bremsstrahlung radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) comes from decelerating electrons. If you accelerate or decelerate a charged particle then it will emit electromagnetic radiation.

In an X-ray tube electrons are emitted by the gun and directed onto a metal target where they scatter off the nuclei and electrons in the metal. As the incoming electrons are scattered they are accelerated and this emits the X-ray photons. If the electron is scattered only a little then it emits a low energy photon, and if it's scattered a lot it emits a high energy photon.

The reason the intensity falls with photon energy is because to be scattered a lot an incoming electron has to score a direct hit on one of the nuclei in the metal target, and nuclei are pretty small. As a rough guide a nucleus is a few femtometres across, while an atom is around 100,000 femtometres across. This means most of the incoming electrons will miss the nuclei in the target by a wide margin, which means they are scattered only a bit and emit only low energy photons. Only a very few electrons will pass close enough to the nucleus to be scattered strongly and emit a high energy electron.